# UICollectionView Items with Variable Sizes Placements

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am displaying a UICollectionView with some phrases/words. Each phrase can be different size. For some reason there is a big gap between few of my phrases as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am using the following code to determine the size of each cell.

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                   layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                          sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let phrase :String = self.phrases[indexPath.row]

        let size = phrase.sizeWithAttributes(nil)

        let doubleSize = CGSize(width: size.width * 2, height: size.height * 2)

        print("\(size.width) and \(size.height)");

        return doubleSize
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: Why is there a space where I am pointing the arrow?

Comment: Because it's like "Justified" text. It performs in order to the first item to "stick" to the left and the last on the line to the right?

Comment: Is there anyway to make it flow more naturally. Without having huge spaces between them?

Comment: You need to implement a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Yep.  That space has to go somewhere.  They default layout object (FlowLayout) just puts it between the items on the row.  You can implement a custom layout object where you specify the rect for each cell and you can math it up however you want, or you can play games with the size of the cells you're creating and use padding inside the cell to position the view you actually care about.

Comment: If you want more specific help, please actually provide some clue as to what you expected.  Just saying there shouldn't be space there doesn't help.  What should be there?  Where should the space go?